# tikz/pgf: do not know the key/undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

Sorry if the title is not very descriptive, but my problem is that I'm at such a loss that I don't even know how to best describe it. The problem is that I have LaTeX errors with certain tikz figures, but only the second time they're used. Here's a MWE, or rather, a MnonWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,shape=cylinder,aspect=0.5] (db) at (0,0) {DB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,shape=cylinder,aspect=0.5] (db) at (0,0) {DB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/aspect', to which you pas
sed '0.5', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17     \node[draw,shape=cylinder,aspect=0.5]
                                               (db) at (0,0) {DB};
```

It gets worse, though. I'd rather not leave off the offending "aspect" in the second figure (and why is it a problem to start with, if it worked fine in the first one?), but if I do remove "aspect=0.5" from the second figure, I run into a different error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...y \pgfutil@tempdima \pgfshapeaspect 
                                                  \pgf@ya \pgfutil@tempdimb ...
l.17 ...e[draw,shape=cylinder] (db) at (0,0) {DB};
```

At this point, I am at a loss. I feel like I messed up something very basic, but can't see it.

Comment: Pull the `tikzlibrary{shapes}` out into the preamble before `begin{document}`.

Comment: Argh! I feared it would be something embarrassing. That worked, thanks! Though I'm still wondering why it leads to these weird errors instead of, for example, simply refusing multiple `\usetikzlibrary` commands.
Plus, it only seems to produce problem with some shapes, like cylinder. When I played around a bit more and replaced it by an ellipse, it worked.

Comment: Hi, @flosch, welcome; for the first scenario, I got the same errors as you mentioned, but for the ellipse case, I got the first error, then hit the enter key does give me the ellipse. Having no idea why, but I would say both are not the right way to go about.

Comment: @Jesse no need to put it in the preamble. Outside of `figure` environment is enough. But I agree that a good practice is to put it before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: OK, yes. I do recall some cases i run/saw before now after reading your remark. Thanks.

Comment: @Jesse care to answer?

Comment: @Jesse Would you like to write up a quick answer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The reason I did not do that on the first request from Paul was thinking, after  viewing all the comments, it is better served as a comment than an answer.  Thanks again for your kindness, but  I, quite often, voted to close low-quality answers a lots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a failure to load the required code.